# Find Source for Portlet

Tags: liferay

To learn more how to implement portlets in Liferay, I want to view the src of existing portlets, e.g. the "Documents and Media" Portlet. Where can I find this src code? I downloaded the src of Liferay but I cant find the relevant files.

[image: tree]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to learn more about building portlets in Liferay is probably to check out the Liferay Plugins repository, rather than Liferay Portal source.

Some Liferay portlets come OOTB in Liferay Portal itself -- that's  what @ArtemKhojoyan is mentioning above. However, as these portlets are pretty thoroughly integrated with the portal itself, they may not be super helpful in figuring out how to make a plugin to deploy on Liferay.

To check out some more standalone portlets, download the [Plugins repo](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins) -- either by cloning the source on github with https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins.git, or downloading a plugins SDK at http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-portal/additional-files -- and open up the `portlets/` folder -- that's probably going to be more helpful in showing you hot-deployable portlets that will be more similar to something you'd make yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For Liferay 6.2.0:

Java: `\liferay-portal-src-6.2.0-ce-ga1\portal-impl\src`

JSP: `\liferay-portal-src-6.2.0-ce-ga1\portal-web\docroot\html\portlet`

Your required case:

Java: `\liferay-portal-src-6.2.0-ce-ga1\portal-impl\src\com\liferay\portlet\documentlibrary`

JSP: `\liferay-portal-src-6.2.0-ce-ga1\portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\document_library`

Comment: I cant see how to match this files in a dev portlet structure like the img shows above.

Comment: Your mentioned portlet (Documents and Media) is part of Liferay and these sources are part of "liferay-portal-src" project, which can be found on Liferay.com. Download it and you will see the structure I have explained.

Comment: I already downloaded the src code of liferay and could find the directories you mentioned. What I try to bulid from that files is portlet project in eclipse, that I can run and deploy from eclipse.

Comment: Which version is your liferay? Maybe that's the reason you can't see my mentioned folders. Also, for building custom plugins you need to download liferay-plugin-sdk (while my given sources belong to liferay-portal pfoject and not plugins-sdk).

Comment: I can see your mentioned folders. version `liferay-portal-src-6.2.0-ce-ga1` and the sources are `liferay-portal-src-6.2.0-ce-ga2`. I have also downloaded the plugin sdk.